# How to analyze "changed |= collection.add(iterator.next()" in java CollectionUtils.class addAll method?

Tags: java

When i read source code of java , The addAll() method in CollectionUtils is hard to understand, need help. Thanks.

```
public static <C> boolean addAll(Collection<C> collection, Iterator<? extends C> iterator) {
    boolean changed;
    for(changed = false; iterator.hasNext(); changed |= collection.add(iterator.next())) {
        ;
    }

    return changed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this loop adds all the elements from the iterator to the collection, but also keeps track of whether the collection has changed at all.

`collection.add(iterator.next())` returns `true` if the item has been actually added .

For the `changed |= collection.add(iterator.next())` part, this is a boolean operation, it is a OR operation .

`true | true` yields `true`

`true | false` also yields `true`

Which means once `changed` gets the value `true`, it will still be `true` after the loop.

This is the information that `addAll` returns, has the collection changed as a result (that is, did *any* of the iterations change the collection), or not.